# wix customaction UAC dtf

Tags: iis-7, wix, uac, custom-action

I am creating Wix installer for IIS website with possibility in UI choose website, app pool and choose virtual directory. Thing is: I successfully created installer, which works with UAC off, but with UAC set to max. i get error - from MSI log:

MSI (c) (A0:C8) [16:41:21:692]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Users\kovac\AppData\Local\Temp\MSI1AEF.tmp, Entrypoint: EnumerateIISWebSitesAndAppPools
MSI (c) (A0:CC) [16:41:21:692]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (A0:CC) [16:41:21:692]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (A0:CC) [16:41:21:692]: Connected to service for CA interface.
SFXCA: Extracting custom action to temporary directory: C:\Users\kovac\AppData\Local\Temp\MSI1AEF.tmp-\
SFXCA: Binding to CLR version v4.0.30319
Calling custom action WebAppInstallCustomActions!WebAppInstallCustomActions.CustomActions.EnumerateIISWebSitesAndAppPools
EnumerateIISWebSitesAndAppPools: Begin
EnumerateIISWebSitesAndAppPools: ATTEMPTING TO RUN WITHOUT ADMIN RIGHTS
CustomAction EnumerateIISWebSitesAndAppPools returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 16:41:23: EnumerateIISWebSitesAndAppPools. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (A0:B0) [16:41:23:878]: Doing action: FatalError
Action 16:41:23: FatalError.

I tried to follow articles - all i just understood was that i should run my custom action with Impersonate="no" so i did but with no success
Additional info: there is no asking from UAC if custom action can be run with right or notm it just ends installer...

```
<CustomAction Id="EnumerateIISWebSitesAndAppPools"
              BinaryKey="WebAppCA"
              DllEntry="EnumerateIISWebSitesAndAppPools"
              Execute="immediate"
              Return="check" Impersonate="no" />
```

Also i read somewhere that actions needs to be run as deffered - but in this case it is not possible - as i need list of websites for user before installing.

My question is how can i run custom action with full right - with UAC on, specifically how are UAC related to admin rights applied on running CA? appreciate any help or any suggestion what to... 
As i don't know importance and problem domain i rather attach custom action script written in C#:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Adds the II7 web sites and the application pool names to the 
    /// ComboBox table in the MSI file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="session">
    /// The installer session.
    /// </param>
    /// <returnenter code heres>
    /// Always returns ActionResult.Success, otherwise rethrows the error
    /// encountered.
    /// </returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">
    /// Thrown if the <paramref name="session"/> parameter is null.
    /// </exception>
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult EnumerateIISWebSitesAndAppPools(
                                                            Session session)
    {

        Debugger.Launch();

        if (null == session)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("session");
        }

        session.Log("EnumerateIISWebSitesAndAppPools: Begin");

        // Check if running with admin rights and if not, log a message to
        // let them know why it's failing.
        if (false == HasAdminRights())
        {
            session.Log("EnumerateIISWebSitesAndAppPools: " +
                        "ATTEMPTING TO RUN WITHOUT ADMIN RIGHTS");
            return ActionResult.Failure;
        }

        session.Log("EnumerateIISWebSitesAndAppPools: " +
                                "Getting the IIS 7 management object");
        ActionResult result;
        using (ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager())
        {
            result = EnumSitesIntoComboBox(session, iisManager);
            if (ActionResult.Success == result)
            {
                result = EnumAppPoolsIntoComboBox(session, iisManager);
            }
        }

        session.Log("EnumerateIISWebSitesAndAppPools: End");
        return result;
    }
```

private static ActionResult EnumSitesIntoComboBox(Session session,
                                                       ServerManager iisManager)
        {
            try
            {
                // Debugger.Break();
                session.Log("EnumSites: Begin");

```
            // Grab the combo box but make sure I'm getting only the one 
            // from WebAppInstallDlg.
            View view = session.Database.OpenView(
           "SELECT * FROM ComboBox WHERE ComboBox.Property='WEBSITE_NAME'");
            view.Execute();

            Int32 index = 1;
            session.Log("EnumSites: Enumerating the sites");
            foreach (Site site in iisManager.Sites)
            {
                // Create a record for this web site. All I care about is
                // the name so use it for fields three and four.
                session.Log("EnumSites: Processing site: {0}", site.Name);
                Record record = session.Database.CreateRecord(4);
                record.SetString(1, "WEBSITE_NAME");
                record.SetInteger(2, index);
                record.SetString(3, site.Name);
                record.SetString(4, site.Name);

                session.Log("EnumSites: Adding record");
                view.Modify(ViewModifyMode.InsertTemporary, record);
                index++;
            }

            view.Close();

            session.Log("EnumSites: End");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            session.Log("EnumSites: exception: {0}", ex.Message);
            throw;
        }

        return ActionResult.Success;
    }

    static bool HasAdminRights()
    {
        WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
        return principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All ca's scheduled in the UI sequence have to be immediate.  Impersonation doesn't apply to immediate ca's.  Best practice is for the UI to not be elevated so best practice says the CA shouldn't require eleveated privs.  If there is no way around this, you'll need to use a bootstrapper to invoke the MSI and elevate it before calling it.

Comment: seems this is hard Fact for me, as i needed to retrieve that info...but still i don't get how W7 UAC is modifing access - i thought UAC should be in charge of notifications to user if any change is about to procced, however from this situation seems, that it incluence access right which are applied during install what i don't get much...

Comment: Now i got loads of questions which arised: iam not really sure about impersonation concept - how it really works - if set to YES then process of installer is executed with access right of current user - however i am logged with admin account, then i should have already full rights. And in case impersonation set to NO - with what right custom action being executed? if i run msi with full admin rights, will be rights same right applied on custom actions by default - or does have impersonation to do anything with it? appreciate any reaction or source for begginers

Comment: UAC works by presenting administrators a standard user privilege token set.  When you request elevation you get the full set.   Impersonation setting is for deferred custom actions and controls whether it impersonates the calling user or runs without impersonation and therefore invoking as SYSTEM.  This is possible since execute sequence is running server side as a windows service running as SYSTEM.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, For instance if SYSTEM run anything, it always - in this case Custom action it has "full privilage token set", right? but if i run without impersonate, then i still should have full rights - iam logged as user with admin rights then what's point to run custom action in with setting impersonation to NO in this case?

Comment: One thing is weird here - we used previous installer generated via vdproj - it allowed us to load IIS information to UI sequence, without elevated privilages set by user. How this is done is unclear to me, do they extract information about IIS site somehow without need of privilages or how they avoid it or does any native support exists?

Answer (score 1):

You collect the data in the UI mode with a dialog, that will set a bunch of properties that you then use in a deferred custom action with no UI. Deferred CAs run with the privilege you need if you set package InstallPrivileges elevated. If you really want to do all this in the code you've written, run it AFTER the install with an elevation manifest to configure what the website.

Or just see if the WiX IIS extension will do what you want. Or maybe this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/115036/Creating-WIX-Installer-for-ASP-NET-Web-Application

This has all been done so many times before that it's not worth re-inventing it again.

Comment: I forgot to highlight specifically what i really face - i got custom dialog which is filled with names of avaiable websites + app Pools + textfield to choose Virtual directory on IIS, so i needed before install(to know where to copy) - and for this task iam calling above custom action to enumerate into combobox - before start of installation. Iam using IIS extension which install correcly, however UAC makes it difficult IMHO

Comment: If the custom dialog is part of the MSI'd early UI sequence then Chris's answer applies. The UI sequence is not elevated unless you launch the MSI with an elevated launcher. That's why many people do this with a standalone configuration program afterwards. Also, that number of UI choices can be interesting to look at as a developer, but installs should just go ahead and do something that works. Unless your clients are experts, how would they know what choices to make? The idea that clients should be shown a bunch of info to choose from is not often a friendly choice.

Comment: thanks for comment, it inspered me to look at issue more with widely out of box